# Is it possible to automate ffmpeg-normalize in java?

Tags: java, python, ffmpeg

I need to use ffmpeg-normalize (https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize) to properly normalize audio files in my java program but ffmpeg-normalize requires manual installation and command usage.

I thought I could automate it in java using ProcessBuilder but it's been proving somewhat impossible.

ffmpeg-normalize is written in python, so I tried every stackoverflow question that relates to running python commands in java. None of them worked, it seems windows just refuses to allow java to run commands in general.

I added python to my environment variables as well. No dice. Windows keeps telling me it doesn't recognize `python` nor `py` nor `pip` as valid internal or external commands.

This is my final code, I tried all other solutions before this including Runtime.exe, using "cmd /c start", and all other derivatives of that.

My last attempt was running a .bat file from the java cmd processor and have the .bat do the rest, but not only is that windows only, but also fails.

Running `pip` in a cmd from cmd.exe directly (outside the java program I mean), it runs properly and shows me the help menu for pip. When the cmd opens from the java app, windows refuses to acknowledge the existence of python all together like in the image below.

[image: .]

```
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + installerBat.getAbsolutePath(), null, ffNormExtractDir);
                StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream());
                StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream());
                errorGobbler.start();
                outputGobbler.start();
                try {
                    process.waitFor();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

I expected the java-born cmd to run the commands instantly and perfectly, but it simply refuses to run them.

So what is my best approach to make installing ffmpeg-normalize a breeze to the user?

Comment: if you read the output of the gobbles it might help you  see what's happenng

Comment: @gpasch I don't think that matters right now because I can see the output directly in the cmd.